# Using requisite injection to order states

Tags: configuration-management, dependency-management, salt

Given three states, `/root/a`, `/root/b` and `/root/c`, I want `/root/c` to execute before `/root/b`, and `/root/b` to execute before `/root/a`.

Given a Salt SLS file `salt://ordertest/init.sls`:

```
/root/a:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/a
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600 

/root/b:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/b
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600 

/root/c:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/c
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600
```

I can test to see the order in which the listed states would be applied. You'll see `/root/a` precede `/root/b`, and `/root/b` preceed `/root/c`.

```
$ salt my-minion-id state.apply ordertest test=True
my-minion-id:
----------
          ID: /root/a
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/a is set to be changed
     Started: 13:54:23.538144
    Duration: 31.765 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: /root/b
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/b is set to be changed
     Started: 13:54:23.570065
    Duration: 16.632 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: /root/c
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/c is set to be changed
     Started: 13:54:23.586831
    Duration: 17.124 ms
     Changes:

Summary for my-minion-id
------------
Succeeded: 3 (unchanged=3)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     3
Total run time:  65.521 ms
```

If we use `require` to directly tell `/root/b` to require `/root/`, and `/root/c` to require `/root/b`:

```
/root/a:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/a
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600
    - require:
      - /root/b

/root/b:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/b
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600
    - require:
      - /root/c

/root/c:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/c
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600
```

We get the ordering we want:

```
$ salt my-minion-id state.apply ordertest test=True
my-minion-id:
----------
          ID: /root/c
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/c is set to be changed
     Started: 13:32:33.624165
    Duration: 31.807 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: /root/b
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/b is set to be changed
     Started: 13:32:33.656166
    Duration: 17.247 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: /root/a
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/a is set to be changed
     Started: 13:32:33.673589
    Duration: 17.126 ms
     Changes:

Summary for my-minion-id
------------
Succeeded: 3 (unchanged=3)
Failed:    0
 ------------
Total states run:     3
Total run time:  66.180 ms
```

But if we try to use `require_in` to have `/root/c` place itself before `/root/b`:

```
/root/a:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/a
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600
    - require:
      - /root/b

/root/b:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/b
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600

/root/c:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://ordertest/c
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 600
    - require_in:
      - /root/b
```

It doesn't work; `/root/c` stays at the end of the sequence:

```
my-minion-id:
----------
          ID: /root/b
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/b is set to be changed
     Started: 13:36:54.037214
    Duration: 32.401 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: /root/a
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/a is set to be changed
     Started: 13:36:54.069797
    Duration: 16.968 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: /root/c
    Function: file.managed
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /root/c is set to be changed
     Started: 13:36:54.086908
    Duration: 17.349 ms
     Changes:

Summary for my-minion-id
------------
Succeeded: 3 (unchanged=3)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     3
Total run time:  66.718 ms
```

Here, you can see that `/root/b` was ordered before `/root/a` as appropriate, but `/root/c` did not get ordered before `/root/b`.

So how can I get this to work? I could use `order` instead of `require` and `require_in`, but that would mean I couldn't use `require` targeting any state that uses `order`, which could get quite messy and poorly-defined.

Comment: I think you may have gotten the wrong letters here; `I want /root/c to execute before /root/b, and /root/b to execute before /root/c` - you have b/c twice?

Comment: Good catch. My mind went numb preparing this question, thanks to a bunch of formatting headaches. Fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turns out to be a [known issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/40771#issuecomment-295406214):

> The require_in requisite does not support everything that require does, mainly id does not support sls or state_id without specifying a state module.

So by modifying our SLS file to include the state module (specifying `file: /root/b` as the `require_in` target instead of simply `/root/b`), we get the correct result.

I don't know if the other requisite injectors (`watch_in`, etc.) have the same limitations, so I will likely standardize my coding style on explicitly including module names in such identifiers.